# Writing the company name in a patent bib resource

Tags: biblatex

For my Master Thesis I need to cite patents. One patent is held by a company. By adding the company as an author I get B. F. GmbH instead of the complete name. Same happens, when I enter the company as a holder. How can I force biblatex to print out the whole name?

I use biblatex with chem-angew as style.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtexu,style=chem-angew,firstinits=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Masterthesis}


\begin{document}

wurde als Imprägniermittel für Leder patentiert\cite{Lederimpr}. 

\newpage \printbibliography \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literatur}

\end{document}
```

That is the .bib entry

```
@Patent{Lederimpr,
  Title                    = {Process for Rendering Leather and Skins Water-Resistant},
  Nationality              = {Deutschland},
  Number                   = {DE1960B057177 19600323},
  Year                     = {1961},
  Holder                   = {(Boehme Fettchemie GmbH)},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

In the `Holder` field, add an additional pair of braces. Also remove the parenthesis, since they are already added by `biblatex`.

```
@Patent{Lederimpr,
  Title                    = {Process for Rendering Leather and Skins Water-Resistant},
  Nationality              = {Deutschland},
  Number                   = {DE1960B057177 19600323},
  Year                     = {1961},
  Holder                   = {{Boehme Fettchemie GmbH}},
}
```

Thus, with your MWE, you get

[image]